# why the mesh moves from its position with curve modifier

Tags: modifiers

When i add a curve modifier stairs moves from its position. How it works can u explain in detail.How to set correct position from where i have the exact position i have set. Rotation scale and position are all 0,0,1 of stairs and curve. In some cases why we have to move and adjust. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image: I want to achieve this way]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem by following the steps:

1. Set the origin of the curve and the stairs to the geometry
2. Move the stairs downward on the x-axis to where the arrow is
3. Rotate it on the y-axis to be parallel to the arrow (Do it in the front orthographic view
4. move it along the x and the z axis repeatedly to find the best fit.
   Which will give you this:[image]

For getting a much more refined curve I added in another nurbs curve and did a lot of tweaking. Added in plane.Modeled it into a stair added in an array modifier and a curve modifier.And finally this is what I got:[image]

Here is the .blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nvo0X5z172oPs1BdGVXNDQF2nUX20u_j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have added image in question i want to achieve in that way.

Comment: as compare to reference image the starting and end stair are flat and in your image its bend.

Comment: Ok I edited my post...Tweak the curve a bit more to get it perfectly

Comment: Looks good now can u plz share the file